# Xcode Linker command failed with exit code 1 AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, build, linker

I am trying to build an already existing iOS project. And I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried deleting `Library Search Paths`, installing `pods` with `pod install`,  running `.workspace` but nothing is working.

Comment: I want to help but I can't because I haven't it, in my opinion, you can push your project in GitHub Repo to allow us to help you and good luck

Comment: Create a new project, re-add your .h/.m/.swift/Podfile files, run `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:
1. Go build setting
2. Find other linker command
3. Delete **lAFNetworking** from there
4. Clean and build